# Element not getting added in List

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a class called Estimate and it has the following field and property:

```
private IList<RouteInformation> _routeMatrix;
public virtual IList<RouteInformation> RouteMatrix
{
    get
    {
        if (_routeMatrix != null && _routeMatrix.Count > 0)
        {
            var routeMatrix = _routeMatrix.ToList();
            routeMatrix =
                    routeMatrix.OrderBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelType).ThenBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelValue).ToList();
            return routeMatrix;
        }
        else return _routeMatrix;
    }
    set { _routeMatrix = value; }
}
```

So, in the getter method, I am just sorting the _routeMatrix by Level Type and then by Level Value and returning the sorted list.

In one of my programs, I have the following code:

```
public void SaveApprovers(string[] approvers)
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var approver in approvers)
    {
        var role = Repository.Get<Role>(long.Parse(approver));
        var level = new Models.Level
        {
            LevelType = LevelType.Approver,
            LevelValue = (LevelValue)i,
            Role = role
        };
        Repository.Save(level);
        var routeInformation = new Models.RouteInformation
        {
            Level = level,
            RouteObjectType = RouteObjectType.Estimate,
            RouteObjectId = _estimate.Id
        };
        Repository.Save(routeInformation);
        _estimate.RouteMatrix.Add(routeInformation); // <--- The problem is here
        Repository.Save(_estimate);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, if there are multiple approvers (i.e: the length of the `approvers` array is greater than 1, only the first `routeInformation` is added in the `RouteMatrix`. I don't know what happen to the rest of them, but the Add method doesn't give any error.

Earlier, RouteMatrix was a public field. This problem started occuring after I made it private and encapsulated it in a public property.

Comment: what is var routeMatrix = _routeMatrix.ToList(); for? var routeMatrix = _routeMatrix.OrderBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelType).ThenBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelValue).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get` member returns a *different* list, you add to that temporary list.

```
 get
 {
    if (_routeMatrix != null && _routeMatrix.Count > 0)
    {
        var routeMatrix = _routeMatrix.ToList(); // ToList creates a _copy_ of the list
        ...
        return routeMatrix;
    }
    else return _routeMatrix;
 }

 .....

 _estimate.RouteMatrix.Add(routeInformation);   // add to the result of ToList()
```

I think the moral here is not to make getters too complicated. The sorting is wasted effort anyway when you just want to Add().

Also, bad things will happen when `_routeMatrix == null`. That may not happen but then the `if (_routeMatrix != null && ...)` part is misleading noise.

Answer (score 2):

When you are applying `ToList()` then completely new list is created, which is not related to original `_routeMatrix` list. Well, they share same elements, but when you add or remove elements from one of lists, it does not affect second list.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

> You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached
>   copy of the query results.

So, you have cached **copy** of your `_routeMatrix` which you are successfully modifying.

---

To solve this issue you can return *IEnumerable* instead of *IList* (to disable collection modifications outside of estimation class), and create `AddRouteInformation` method to estimation class which will add route information to `_routeMatrix`. Use that method to add new items:

```
_estimate.AddRouteInformation(routeInformation);
Repository.Save(_estimate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not actually modifying `_routeMatrix`, you're modifying a copy of it. Don't issue the `ToList` on `_routeMatrix`, just sort it. Change the `get` to this:

```
get
{
    if (_routeMatrix != null && _routeMatrix.Count > 0)
    {
        _routeMatrix =
                _routeMatrix.OrderBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelType).ThenBy(tm => tm.Level.LevelValue).ToList();
        return _routeMatrix;
    }
    else return _routeMatrix;
}
```